# How to generate a diagram of all Java program method calls in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a large Java code base that I am currently working through and would like it if I could have a call trace diagram of all method calls made within the program. To be more clear, each time a method is called or returned from I want that event to be logged into a file or diagram.

Is there anything inside of IntelliJ IDEA that would do this automatically for me?

I have been using the Java Flight Recorder but it doesn't appear to be logging every method call for me. I have also looked into the Java Debugger (jdb) which records information about method calls but it builds no diagram or flow chart.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably need [a profiler](https://www.yourkit.com/features/events/).

Comment: Flight Recorder works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for help, fellas.